# How to use mask with transparency on QWidget?

Tags: qt5, mask, qwidget

I am trying to use mask on my QWidget. I want to overlay existing widget with row of buttons - similar to Skype

[image: skype buttons]

Notice that these buttons don't have jagged edges - they are nicely antialiased and widget below them is still visible.
I tried to accomplish that using Qt Stylesheets but on pixels that should be "masked out" was just black colour - it was round button on black, rectangular background.
Then I tried to do this using QWidget::mask(). I used following code

```
QImage alpha_mask(QSize(50, 50), QImage::Format_ARGB32);
alpha_mask.fill(Qt::transparent);

QPainter painter(&alpha_mask);
painter.setBrush(Qt::black);
painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);    
painter.drawEllipse(QPoint(25,25), 24, 24);

QPixmap mask = QPixmap::fromImage(alpha_mask);
widget.setMask(mask.mask());
```

Sadly, it results in following effect
[image: my buttons]
"Edges" are jagged, where they should be smooth. I saved generated mask so I could investigate if it was the problem
[image]
it wasn't.

I know that Linux version of Skype does use Qt so it should be possible to reproduce. But how?

Comment: How about just drawing a circle using an anti aliased QPainter? Masks are always booleans and you can't get antialiasing with them.

Comment: I do that to acquire initial mask (look at code sample). 
I cannot paint QWidget on native window, it is up to Qt.
Do you mean empty QWidget and drawing circle in paintEvent perhaps?

Comment: You can use png image with alpha channel in background.

Comment: I would just call `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);` and not bother with the mask at all, unless you are really pedantic.

Answer (score 3):

One possible approach I see is the following.

1. Prepare a nice high resolution pixmap with the circular button icon over transparent background.
2. Paint the pixmap on a square widget.
3. Then mask the widget leaving just a little bit of margin beyond the border of the circular icon so that the widget mask jaggedness won't touch the smooth border of the icon.

Comment: This may be nice workaround for this problem. Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get a nice circular button with not so much code.
Here is the constructor of my custom button:

```
Button::Button(Type t, QWidget *parent) : QPushButton(parent) {
    setIcon(getIcon(t));
    resize(30,30);
    setMouseTracking(true);
    // here I apply a centered mask and 2 pixels bigger than the button
    setMask(QRegion(QRect(-1,-1,32,32),QRegion::Ellipse));
}
```

and in the style sheet I have the following:

```
Button {
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(136, 0, 170);
}
```

With border-radius I get the visual circle and the mask doesn't corrupt the edges because it is 1 pixel away.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong approach for generating masks. I would generate them from the button images themselves:

```
QImage image(widget.size(), QImage::Format_Alpha8);
widget.render(&image);
widget.setMask(QBitmap::fromImage(image.createMaskFromColor(qRgba(0, 0, 0, 0))));
```

Comment: It is not wrong. I need this for a widget, and I won't rasterize it. I need that mask + opacity for a widget, not for pics.

Comment: It was a long time ago when I wrote this answer, so I don't really remember what I meant, but you have an [example here](https://github.com/user1095108/cairowidget/blob/master/example3.cpp).